# Windows Azure Scheduler Node.js Azure SDK

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-node-sdk

I've been trying to figure out how to use the scheduling API that comes with Windows Node.js Azure SDK:

azure-scheduler

But I can't seem to find any documentation or tutorials on how to use it to create jobs that fire on a certain date that hits an http address.

Has anyone tried using Azure SDK to create a schedule job to the Azure Scheduler?  Can you show us what code you used to get it to work.

Thankyou

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn528941.aspx

Comment: thanks andrew, but I'm looking for something that invokes the Azure Node.js SDK library. I see they install the azure-scheduler library but their are no examples how to use it.  I can take a stab in the dark and figure it out through trial and error but examples would be better. thanks.